# Jmeter- Web services- Generate token key

Tags: jmeter

in Jmeter is it possible to call a c# dll which generates a token key and send it part of the web service request.

If Jmeter cannot do it can you please suggest some other tool that can.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible but if you know how the token is generated, you can use a `BeanShell Sampler`.

You'll find some documentation here:

- http://www.beanshell.org/manual/quickstart.html
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Sampler
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting

If you are familiar with Java it's pretty straight forward and you can also import Java libraries.